# Export KVM VM to HyperV

Tags: centos, qemu, kvm, virsh

We have a VM running on CentOS KVM that we want to export to MS Hyper V.

We saw the instructions to export the image here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2015/06/22/handy-tool-for-converting-kvm-vmware-images-to-hyper-v/

Using qemu-img, we can convert the image as following:

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 “SourceDisk.img” -O vhdx -o subformat=dynamic “Destination.vhdx”
```

However, we're not sure how to create the SourceDisk.img from running VM.

Comment: `SourceDisk.img` is just the name of your current disk image for your vm. If its split over multiple `.img` or `.vdk` files you will need to convert it to a single image. Check the startup config of the current vm it should give you the disk info. TAKE A BACKUP FIRST before you run the commands in case it goes wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We found the image at the following location:

```
/var/lib/libvirt/images/<VM_NAME>.img
```